# nagiosgraph & windows - mapping issue?

Tags: nagios

I've just started using NSClient++ to monitor a selection of Windows hosts, and have been asked to set up Nagiosgraph for monitoring.

I have a map to graph my memory checks, which should graph an average for 5 mins and one for 30.

```
# Service type: ntload
# check command: check_nt -H Address -v CPULOAD -l5,70,90,30,70,90
# output: CPU Load 9% (5 min average) 11% (30 min average)
# perfdata: 5 min avg Load=9%;70;80;0;100 30 min avg Load=11%;70;90;0;100
#/perfdata:.*5 min avg Load=(d+)%;(d+);(d+);d+;d+ 30 min avg Load=(d+)%;d+;d+;d+;d+ /
/output:.*?(d+)% .*?(d+)% /
and push @s, [ ntload,
[ avg05min, GAUGE, $1 ],
[ avg30min, GAUGE, $2 ] ];
```

The 5min check is graphing, however the 30 min check is flat-lining at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `(d+)`s should be `(\d+)`. Not sure if this a copy/paste error or the source of the problem though, because as it is now, both your graphs shouldn't be graphing anything.

Comment: yeah sorry it's a weird copy+paste error, I do indeed have \'s where they should be.